# Returning a boolean true or false using the radio button?

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
<input type="radio" name="mobileActivation" value="no" id="donotactivatemobile" onchange="disable_link();" onclick="checkBoxDisabling()" <?php if (isset($_POST['mobileActivation']) && $_POST['mobileActivation']=="no") $_POST['uclActivation'] = FALSE; ?> />

<input type="radio" name="mobileActivation" value="yes" id="activatemobile" onchange="enable_link();" onclick="checkBoxEnabling()"  <?php if (isset($_POST['mobileActivation']) && $_POST['mobileActivation']=="yes") $_POST['mobileActivation'] = TRUE;  ?> />
```

I can't seem to make the return value into a boolean? I am still getting the value yes and no :( But not TRUE or false. Can anybody help? I've already tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13968827/how-to-make-a-radio-button-return-boolean-true-false-instead-of-on-off) but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this trick:

```
<input type="radio" name="mobileActivation" value="0" /> false <br>
<input type="radio" name="mobileActivation" value="1">   true  <br>
```

Then you can check the value as below:

```
if(isset($_GET['mobileActivation'])) {
    $phone = (bool) $_GET['mobileActivation'];
    if($phone === true)
        echo("mobileActivation is true");
    else {
        echo("mobileActivation is false");
    }
}
```

This works because 0 in PHP is treated as false boolean value, all other integers except 0 are treated as true boolean values.